# Best use of Google code wiki for project documentation

Tags: documentation, google-code

I've recently moved my project from sourceforge to Google code.  I'm intrigued by the Google code wiki that is integrated with svn, but I'm not sure of the best way to use it to provide project documentation.

For my project, documentation could appear in three places: (1) on the wiki, (2) in the desktop application I'm developing (using wxPython), and (3) on the project website (which is http://www.openstv.org and is Drupal based).

I like the idea of using the Google code wiki as the primary source of the documentation, and then automatically incorporating this documentation in both the desktop application and on the project website .

Does anyone have any suggestions for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wiki files live in Subversion -- just `svn checkout http://yourproject.googlecode.com/svn/wiki yourwiki` and you get a `yourwiki` SVN repository that's easy to keep updated (just `svn up` in it once in a while, e.g. in a crontab).

The format of the Wiki files is a [Google variant](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/WikiSyntax) of [ReSTructured Text](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) so you could write scripts to convert it to plain ReST and from there to whatever other formats you prefer for your other uses -- or, write ReST on your system, convert it to whatever you like (including perhaps Google's wiki format;-), and upload that...

Comment: Nit: the syntax is actually of Google's own devising. As far as I know, there's a dearth of libraries that can parse the .wiki syntax into other formats

http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/WikiSyntax

But this answer is very much correct in that ReST can be infinitely converted. If you're using Python already, you could write the docs in ReST under the Sphinx build system and then compile it to static HTML that's served off of Google's SVN servers rather than using Google's ad-hoc syntax.

Comment: thanks for the clarification -- I'll edit my answer accordingly!